# Large Family of Subsets with small overlap

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find upper and lower bounds on the cardinality of the largest family of subsets of an $n $ element set, $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots ,n\})$ , if no pair of elements contain a third element that is

$A\not\subset B\cup C $ for any $A,B,C\in \mathcal{S}$.

Does anyone have any idea how to get nontrivial bounds for example if we take $\mathcal{S}=\{\{1\},\{2\},\dots \{n\}\}$ we get the lower bound of $n$ and you can easily get an upper bound of $2^{n-1}-1$. I know through so constructions  that one can get $c*n$ (for some $c>1$)but I want to know can one do fundamentally better than this for both the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Presumably you want $A, B, C$ to be **distinct** elements of $\mathcal S$, otherwise $A=B$ is a counterexample whenever $C$ is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: How do you get $c n$ for $c > 1$?  I can prove that the best lower bound is $n$ for $n \le 5$.

Comment: ... and now for $n \le 6$.

Comment: It was through construction a construction (on a ten point set) where I just choose sets in such a way that I got 11 sets... I thought that the idea could be generalized to higher $n$ but my office mate has since erased it off our chalkboard and I don't really remember what sets I picked. Also I could have just made a mistake about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal T$ be the set of all unions of two distinct elements of $\mathcal S$.
Each $T \in \mathcal T$ contains exactly two distinct members of $\mathcal S$, and in particular $\mathcal T$ is an antichain.  By Sperner's theorem, the largest possible antichain in $\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,n\})$ has cardinality ${n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, while $|\mathcal T| = |\mathcal S| (|\mathcal S|-1)/2$, 
so 
$$|\mathcal S| \le \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 8 {n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}}{2} \sim \text{const} \dfrac{2^{n/2}}{n^{1/4}} $$

Comment: Thanks that is a real slick proof I hand no idea of the existence of Sperner's theorem.